# How can I get a program to launch on startup without creating a duplicate taskbar icon?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7. I want a program (HexChat, an IRC client) to launch on startup. I also want it pinned to my taskbar. The problem is, if I just put a shortcut to the program in the Startup folder (*C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup*), then I get a second icon on the taskbar.

[image: Duplicate entries]

How can I get a program to launch on startup, but use the icon that's already on the taskbar? I know this is possible since Skype behaves like that.

Comment: So you have 2 separate instances of hexchat running? Why are you trying to start another one if there is already one automatically running?

Comment: I believe that what Jack means is that usually, if you click on HexChat on the Task Bar, HexChat's window will be found where the pinned icon is; but if he starts HexChat via Autostart, HexChat's window will not be found in the pinned icon, but in a new, "floating" icon. *OT: some programs have that behavior even when starting "regularly", i.e. when starting Capture One with the pinned Task Bar icon, I will get a new, unpinned one for it.*

Comment: To put @DavidPostill's comment another way: if a program is running, it will already be in the task-bar (or possibly the system tray), so why do you need it in the launchpad as well?

Comment: @AFH because Jack wants the autostarted HexChat to start "within" the pinned icon, so that HexChat has a fixed place on his Task Bar. (I think.)

Comment: Go through the.registry process to add startup programs. [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Biswa This worked! Although I have no idea why. Why does starting with a registry value behave differently to starting with a shortcut in the Startup menu?

Comment: Likely, the program has its *AppID* in the shortcut. It's the way Taskbar keeps track of app windows. If you copied its shortcut from Start menu or the pinned one, and then put it into _Startup_ folder, the AppID will be preserved. If you created a new shortcut, it has no AppID, and therefore it's a separate instance. Starting from the registry does not provide additional info, the AppID, therefore the app window gets associated with the pinned icon.